# Use dynamic express routes within another Express route

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, reactjs

For a school project, I created a plugin system for an Express.js-Application in Node.js. The main page of the application should display a dashboard, where every root page of each plugin should be displayed in a div. Every root page is accessible over the pluginName/-route.

What I would like to do is the following: I wanna include the HTML-string of every home-route in the dashboard. But for this, I need to call the routes inside Node.js (like partials) and for some plugins I even have to provide some properties.

Does someone have an idea, how this could be implemented?

e.g. I have following route:

```
    router.get('/pluginName', function(req, res) {
        res.render(__dirname + '/views/home.handlebars', {
            layout: __dirname + '/views/layouts/main.handlebars',
            markup: markup // Pass rendered react markup
        });
    });
```

Now I want to pass the resulting HTML from this route into another route.

So far I had the following ideas:

1. Simply add the URLs of the plugins to a "data-ajax-url" attribute of the divs and load the stuff via AJAX.
2. Make an HTTP-Call to every route and append the result on server side (pretty nasty...).
3. Create a renderDashboard-function for every plugin, where I get the HTML using app.render(...) and then I append the result.

But I'm not really sure, which approach (if any) would be the nicest.

Comment: Why not just call `renderToString` on your components? (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendertostring)

Comment: Well, because I want to be independent from the frontend technology. So plugins should also be able to use e.g. Angular.js. Sorry for not being clear on that.